# C++ allocation segfault

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

I have this code:

```
size_t count = new_data.size();
std::cout << "got the count: " << count << std::endl;
double g_x[count];
std::cout << "First array done\n";
double g_y[count];
std::cout << "Allocated array of size" << count << std::endl;
```

which gives me the output:

```
got the count: 1506538
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I honestly don't understand why. It work on another data set, but not on this one.

Comment: @David wrong. You can. But you shouldnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably just getting a stack overflow here. Try to dynamically allocate the memory, i.e. use the heap.

```
double* g_x = new double[count];
...
delete[] g_x;
```

Even better solution would be to use `std::vector<>`:

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<double> g_x(count); // Creates vector with the specified size.
```

Comment: But you should remember: when you are using `new`, you are around a memory leak if some exception will be thrown in place of `...`. Simply use STL's containers in such situation

Comment: allocating 1506538 double 8byte storage is about 11.5MB!

Comment: @Arcturus, that's okay when it is allocated on **heap**.

Comment: well I usually would use a container, but I have to use a strange framework which doesn't work with those, not even if I pass it a pointer or such

Comment: @BenediktWutzi, interesting. Could you please add the signature of some framework function to the question?

Comment: It's cern's ROOT framework. I'm using the TGraph class to plot some data http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TGraph.html

Comment: @BenediktWutzi, the framework accepts **arrays**: **pointer** to the first element and **number** of elements. For example, `void DrawGraph(Int_t n, const Double_t* x = 0, const Double_t* y = 0, Option_t* option = "")`. To get pointer to the first element for `std::vector<>` just use `&g_x[0]`.

Comment: @BenediktWutzi, please show us the code which can't be not compiled.

Comment: I mean when I try to use &g_x[0]

Comment: @BenediktWutzi, which function of the framework you're trying to call with `&g_x[0]`?

Comment: The constructor of TGraph so TGraph *g = new TGraph(count, &g_x[0], &g_y[0]);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25023/discussion-between-sergey-brunov-and-benedikt-wutzi)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamically sized array, you either need to create it using `new`, or use one of the STL containers.

Take a look at some of the answers at [Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in C and C++ arrays are by definition defined at compile time so what you do is wrong and it's very strange that this code even compile (compiler should scream at you)

However if you need a runtime defined array you should either use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or manually allocate memory (not reccomended if you don't have very specific needs)

P.S. you should check your compiler warning level and the verbosity because this code has **serious flaws** so it shouldn't even compile (it's also bad for you if you have a very low warning level etc because you could pick up some bad coding habits because you are using not knowingly compiler specific extensions to the language and this is going to drive you mad when changing environement)