# Freeing memory for array in c++?

Tags: c++

Should the memory be freed for the array declaration like below and if so how? I only found delete for dynamic array allocation but no proper description for this kind of array.

```
char firstname[20];
```

Comment: For dynamic array allocation, it's `delete[]` not `delete`. But you're better of using `std::vector<>` for dynamic arrays instead, it's got a much easier interface including `.resize`.

Comment: This declares an array that is either global or (inside a function) is automatic. In both cases, the runtime asigns memory and frees it appropiately. Just like if it was an, e.g., `int`.

Answer (score 3):

No, since it is allocated on stack.

I found this thread useful after typing my answer: [C++ Static Array VS Dynamic Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array)