# C++ pointer in class attributes

Tags: c++, pointers, attributes, function-pointers

I am confused about this library code..

what is the purpose of writing pointer in attributes name?
Like string *name;

this is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     class stringlist
     {
     private:
        int numstrings;
        string *strings;
     public:
        stringlist() : numstrings(0), strings(NULL)
        {}
        // copy constructor
        stringlist(const stringlist &other) :
           numstrings(other.numstrings),
           strings(new string[other.numstrings]) {
           for (int i=0; i<numstrings; i++) {
              strings[i] = other.strings[i];
           }
     }
        // destructor
        ~stringlist() {
           if (numstrings > 0) delete [] strings;
        }
        void printStrings();
        const string& getString(int num);
        void setString(int num,
                       const char *astring); 
     void setString(int num,
                 const string &astring);
     int getNumstrings() {
     return numstrings;
     }
     void setNumstrings(int num);
     void swapStrings(stringlist &other) ;
     // overloaded operators
     stringlist& operator =
               (const stringlist &other) {
     stringlist temp(other);
     swapStrings(temp);
     return *this;
     }
     };
```

Can anyone please explain what is the purpose of 
using `string *strings` 
instead of `string strings`?

Thanks all!

Comment: It's an array of strings.

Comment: The person writing the code hadn't heard of `std::vector<std::string>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string *strings;
```

declares a pointer to the first element of an array of strings. Because of C/C++ array/pointer semantics, you can treat this as an array of strings, e.g. index it as `strings[n]` to get the nth element.

```
string strings;
```

would just be one string. Since the class is for holding a list of strings, declaring just one string would not be sufficient.

Comment: It doesn't. It's just a pointer to a string. It just so happens that the intended use is to point at the first element in an array. Yet another reason why pointers can be terribly ambiguous.

Comment: Look at the copy constructor, it initializes `strings(new string[other.numstrings])`. That's allocating an array. Other code that he hasn't shown would be similar to create a new `stringList`.

Comment: Yes, which makes it point at the first element of an array. The declaration is not a pointer to array though. That would look like `string (*strings)[N]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you gave, *strings is used for a `dynamic array`.
You can see that it's allocated with `strings(new string[other.numstrings])` and the destructor deletes it if it's pointing to something.

More on dynamic arrays:
- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

- [Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array)