# C/C++ Allocation

Tags: c++, c, allocation

Giving a number X and reading X numbers into an uni-dimensional array, which of the following ways is the best(fastest as execution time)?

Please note that X is a number between 1 and 1000000

```
scanf("%d", &x);
int array[x];
//continue reading X numbers into array
```

Or

```
scanf("%d", &x);
int array[1000000];
//continue reading X ...
```

Or

```
scanf("%d", &x);
int * array = malloc(x*sizeof(int));
//same as above
free(array);
```

Or the C++ dynamic allocation method?

Note 1: that I am posting this from a mobile phone, I hope the format for the code above is fine, if not, I ask nicely somebody (<3) to edit it, since it is painfull to indent code from a phone.

Note 2: How could I test what I asked above?

Comment: Use a timer to count the time it takes for the three different methods... Although I would definitely ban number 2 `array[1000000]` as if you have only 1 data you loose lots of memory...

Comment: You are using variable length array in first method!

Comment: Do you really care about execution time when using user input?! Will you ever notice any difference?

Comment: You should ask yourself if it is really worth optimizing here. What does your program do with the the scanfed data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ memory allocation for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909753/c-memory-allocation-for-arrays)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The program that I am currently writing has to have a maximal execution time, basically I want things to load faster at a small cost of CPU. Assuming that I have enoguh memory.

Comment: @TudorutRobert if your program has such **strict timing requirements** then stack array allocation (but where array is allocated is implementation defined) is slightly faster (that's why it's what usually done in real-time environments). Note that VLA may be stack allocated too (implementation defined) and they have slightly better performance vs malloc() but they have many other drawbacks. However, in this case, first of all limit answers to C or C++ and describe your specific architecture and requirements. A _general_ answer in this case is just useless.

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there appears `scanf` (and the comments assume that there's another million calls to `scanf`) any questions regarding the memory allocation in combination with "Which is fastest?" can be universally answered with: "Yes" (read as: irrelevant).

While automatic storage ("stack allocation") is generally faster than freestore, it is entirely insignificant compared to the time you will spend in `scanf`. That being said, it is usually (not necessarily, but usually) dynamic *deallocation* which is slow, not allocation.

A couple of points to note in general on that code:

1. Reading an integer from some external source (file, network, argv, whatever) and doing an allocation based on that number **without doing a sanity check** first is massively bad karma. This is bound to cause a problem one day, it is how many existing real-world exploits came into being. Do not trust blindly that any number that you got from somewhere is automatically valid. Even if no malice is involved, *accident* may still provide an invalid number which will cause catastrophic failure.
2. Allocating a non-constant sized array on the stack will work under recent versions of C and will "work" as an extension even under C++ if you use GCC, but it is normally not allowable in C++ (meaning it will fail to compile).
3. Allocating a million integers means roughly 4MB of memory, which is pretty harsh towards your maximum stack size (often only 1MB). *Expect a stack overflow happening*.
4. Allocating an *unknown* number of integers (but expecting the number to be up to a million) is similar to (3).
5. The worst thing re (3) and (4) is that *it may actually succeed*. Which possibly means your program will unexpectedly crash later (encountering a stack overflow), in an entirely unrelated innocent piece of code. And you will wonder why that happens, since the code that crashes looks like it is perfectly valid (and it is, indeed!).

Answer (score 1):

You'll get compilation error for this code:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
int array[x];
```

x should be known at compilation time in this case.

When using `int array[1000000]` you allocate memory on the stack, not in the heap, so it's fundamental difference comparing to `malloc` or `new operator`. It would be faster because it takes actually only one CPU command of modifying stack pointer.

If comparing `malloc` and `new`, `malloc` will be faster because new will eventually call `malloc` inside. But the performance gain will be tiny, It doesn't worth to optimize your c++ program in this way, just use c++ when you need to allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: In C++ i tried it with cin>>x; int array[x]; and it compiles just fine.(i assumed that it works the same in C)

Comment: @CodeFuller also in C (starting from C99) it's valid (and it has been a GCC extension as well). Oh, BTW...do you really really think you can measure performance difference between new and malloc? It's slower (true) but because it does something else...

Comment: Well, may be int array[x] could be compiled with gcc, but standard c++ doesn't support this. In VS you'll get error 'error C2133: 'array' : unknown size'.

Comment: @TudorutRobert I would avoid VLA. Even if some compilers don't complain. VLA is a standard feature of c99. In c++11 is _[a conditional feature which implementations are not required to support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)_

Comment: @CodeFuller as Adriano said, it's valid C (since C99). The fact that C++ doesn't allow this or the fact that the Microsoft compiler gives an error is irrelevant to the fact that variable-length arrays are a valid C language construct. Nonetheless, what I agree with what ZDF says.

Comment: Since C11 Variable Length Arrays are no longer mandatory for C, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision) VS has never had a fully compliant C99 compiler especially with regards to VLA.