# Char pointer assignment not working

Tags: c++, xcode

I have piece of code here.

```
void MyString::rm_left_space(char *s){
    int size = getSize(s);
    char s2[size];
    char *s1=&s2[0];
    int i=0;
    while(*(s+i)==' '){
        i++;
    }
    for (int k=i,l=0; k<size; k++) {//start from i, discarding spaces
        *(s1+l) = *(s+k);
        l++;
    }
    s=s1;
}

void MyString::rm_right_space(char *s){
    int countSpacesfromLast=0;
    int size = getSize(s);
    int j=size-1;
    while(*(s+j)==' '){
        countSpacesfromLast++;
        j--;
    }

    char *s2=new char[size-countSpacesfromLast];
    for (int t=0; t<size-countSpacesfromLast; t++) {
        *(s2+t)=*(s+t);
    }
    s=s2;
}

void MyString::rm_space(char *s){
    rm_left_space(s);
    rm_right_space(s);
}
```

Where there is s=s1 and s=s2 assignment does not happen. How come pointer assignment is not working.

In rm_space method s is unchanged after function calls. Why?

Comment: C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Is there a reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: As for your problem, as any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) should have told you, arguments are by default passed *by value*. Meaning they are *copied* into local variables in the functions. And modifying a copy will not modify the original.

Comment: Lastly, remember that local variables inside a function have a life-time of that function *only*. Pointers to them will become invalid as soon as the function returns and the local variables go out of scope.

Comment: I think the most important thing to understand about pointers is that there is nothing special about them.

Comment: I know all this ... but when i say the pointer thing i got confused. `char *s` when you are passing `int m` and things like that i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In rm_space method s is unchanged after function calls. Why?

Because `s` is passed by value. In other words - it's **not** the variable `s` that is passed but the value that `s` holds. The variable `s` in the called function and the variable `s` in the calling function are **two different variables**. Consequently, changes made to one of them does not change the other.

If you want to change `s` in the calling function inside the called function, you need to use call-by-reference.

Something like:

```
void MyString::rm_left_space(char*& s){
```

However, notice that your code have a major problem as it seems you are trying to assign `s2` in the called function to `s` in the calling function. You should never do that as `s2` goes out of scope as soon as the function returns.

#### Example: Difference between pass-by-value and between pass-by-value

This simple program uses pass-by-value

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x)
{
  x = 42;
  std::cout << "Inside foo: x=" << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 21;
  std::cout << "Before foo: x=" << x << std::endl;
  foo(x);
  std::cout << "After foo: x=" << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Before foo: x=21
Inside foo: x=42
After foo: x=21    // notice x didn't change
```

because `x` in `foo` and in `main` are two different variables.

This simple program uses pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int& x)   // Notice the &
{
  x = 42;
  std::cout << "Inside foo: x=" << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 21;
  std::cout << "Before foo: x=" << x << std::endl;
  foo(x);
  std::cout << "After foo: x=" << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Before foo: x=21
Inside foo: x=42
After foo: x=42   // notice that x changed
```

because now `x` inside `foo` is a reference to `x` in `main`

These examples used `int` but exactly the same applies for pointers.

#### Example: Using pointers

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 21;
int y = 5;

void foo(int* p)
{
  *p = 42;
  p = &y;
  std::cout << "Inside foo:  p = " << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Inside foo: *p = " << *p << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int* p = &x;
  printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
  std::cout << "Before foo:  p = " << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Before foo: *p = " << *p << std::endl;
  foo(p);
  std::cout << "After foo :  p = " << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << "After foo : *p = " << *p << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before foo:  p = 0x60106c
Before foo: *p = 21
Inside foo:  p = 0x601070
Inside foo: *p = 5
After foo :  p = 0x60106c  // Pointer value did NOT change
After foo : *p = 42        // Pointed to value DID change
```

Replacing

```
void foo(int* p)
```

with

```
void foo(int*& p)
```

will give:

```
Before foo:  p = 0x60106c
Before foo: *p = 21
Inside foo:  p = 0x601070
Inside foo: *p = 5
After foo :  p = 0x601070  // Pointer value DID change
After foo : *p = 5         // Consequently, the pointed to value also changed
```

Comment: @Abhijeet It makes no difference that you use pointers. Inside the function you can change the memory that the pointer points to but you can **not** change the value of the pointer.

Comment: I understand the above code with `int` and others. But I am passing a `char *s` from the calling function to the called function.. It is a pointer right...?

Comment: @Abhijeet yes, it's a pointer in your case. It seems you are confused about a) What a **pointer points to** and b) the **value of a pointer**. Those are two very different things.

Comment: lets say below
`int main(){
char[] s[10];
char *ss=&s[0];
rm_space(ss);
}` 
is this not pass by reference? since i am sending a pointer to an array

Comment: ooooo i understand... so the value of the pointer is replaced when the function call happens you say.... which then is sent to `rm_space("blablahblah");`

Then the function gets called right?

Comment: @Abhijeet I added an extra example. Hope it'll make it more clear.

Comment: I understood this today.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to StackOverflow, if there's any mistake, please Kindly judge me

I am not sure that whether I was misunderstand what you mean, so if there's any misunderstanding, please let me know.

I guess you want to do remove left space in a string, right?

e.g.

```
"  Hello" --> "Hello"
```

if so, here is my version

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 7
void rm_left_space(char* s){
    int size = SIZE; //Because I don't know how to getSize, so I use fixed size instead
    char s2[size]; 
    char *s1 = &s2[0];
    int i = 0;
    while(*(s+i) == ' '){
        i++;
    }
    cout << i << endl;
    for (int k=i,l=0; k<size; k++) {//start from i, discarding spaces
        *(s1+l) = *(s+k);
        l++;
    }
    s=s1; // <-- Shallow copy 
}

void rm_left_space_2(char* s){
    int size = SIZE;
    char *s2 = new char[SIZE]; <-- you should use dynamic array instead of static array 
    int space_num = 0;
    while(*(s+space_num) == ' '){
        space_num++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        s2[i] = s[(i + space_num)%size];
    }

    // s = s2; // <--- shallow copy

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){     // You should copy whole array 
        s[i] = s2[i];
    }
}


int main(){

    char s[] = "  hello";
    cout << s << endl;

    rm_left_space_2(s);

    cout << s << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
  hello
hello
```

Also, you could check the post, 
[static array vs dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/static-array-vs-dynamic-array-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)