# Malloc the elements of a struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have the following struct:

```
struct postsTempo {
    int ano;
    ShortData dias[373];
    struct postsTempo* prox;
};
```

When I do `malloc(sizeof(struct postsTempo))` have I allocated everything that I need or do i still need to `malloc` the `ShortData` array? I cant add anything to that array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you allocate memory using `malloc()` it creates the memory space for all variables declared inside the structure.

So there is no need to use `malloc` further for `ShortData`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you don't need to malloc the ShortData array because this is a local array created on the stack, and has automatic storage duration.
Take a look: [Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/static-array-vs-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to say the ShortData array is on the stack, since OP is allocating the storage for the outer `struct postsTempo` with `malloc`.

Comment: In this case, would not ShortData be allocated on the heap because it is part of the struct that was allocated on the heap?  Edit: I see someone has already commented on that.