# Can you mimic dynamic array sizes using 'new' in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, large-data

I know you can make a dynamically sized array using `malloc`, but I'm interested in doing the same thing using `new`, partly because `malloc` is considered bad practice in C++ and mostly out of curiosity.

Say I'm writing a program that will receive an input of bytes that could be as many as `MAX_INPUT_SIZE`, which is so large that allocating an array of that size could potentially impede the ability of other programs to run on the same RAM. However, all input sizes `[0, MAX_INPUT_SIZE]` are equally as likely to be received. Is there a way to write the program in such a way that memory allocation on the heap is proportional to the input size so that performance of other programs are not affected unless a large enough input is received? Assume these restrictions:

- Cannot use `malloc`
- Cannot use `vector` or other wrappers (let's say we are looking for extremely fast performance)
- The algorithm to interpret the data MUST have all data available in one array (for performance reasons, and so that small inputs will still be processed very fast)
- Program should allocate memory approximately equal to input size

These restrictions are unrealistically tight but it's just hypothetical. Here is a potential solution:

```
char *data;
long long int data_size;
/* receive input size */

if( data_size <= 1000 )
    data = new char[1000];

else if( data_size <= 10000 )
    data = new char[10000];
...
else if( data_size <= MAX_INPUT_SIZE / 10 )
    data = new char[MAX_INPUT_SIZE / 10];

else if( data_size <= MAX_INPUT_SIZE )
    data = new char[MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
```

My question is, does the above code actually only allocate `new` memory when its line of code is run, or does it prepare memory for all those `new` calls, and just assign the pointer to the one requested?

Essentially, would this program run on computer where `MAX_INPUT_SIZE` exceeds the available RAM, but the actual `data_size` does not?

If the answer is, yes it would run, then why does `new` force you to have an array size that resolves at compile time? Surely it's possible for the C++ compiler could make `new` allocate dynamically then? If so then is it simply a design choice, and what would be the reasons for disallowing dynamic array size allocation?

If the answer is, no it wouldn't run, is there an alternate solution given the restrictions?

Comment: You asked: *why does new force you to have an array size that resolves at compile time* … but it ***doesn't***!

Comment: What you are looking for is associative containers, like `std::set`, `std::unordered_set`, or perhaps `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. This is what you're looking for. Please see your C++ book for a full explanation.

Comment: You also asked: *Surely it's possible for the C++ compiler could make new allocate dynamically then?* - but it ***does***!

Comment: `if( data_size <= 1000 )
    data = new char[1000];

else if( data_size <= 10000 )
    data = new char[10000];` ?? why not `new char[data_size]` ?

Comment: *Cannot use vector or other wrappers (let's say we are looking for extremely fast performance)* -- Please measure.  Let's see the proof that using `vector` will be slower than whatever you come up with.

Comment: It seems I'm mistaken. Does anyone know what language/senario am I thinking of where you can't have an array length that isn't known at runtime?

Comment: BTW, `new` is [also](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#memory-leaks) considered bad practice. Re: array size, you must be thinking of array objects, as in `char x[1000];`. See [Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/static-array-vs-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: Just use a `std::vector`.  It is just as fast as using `new` as long as you use it right and you turn on optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

> does the above code actually only allocate `new` memory when it's line of code is run, or does it prepare memory for all those `new` calls, and just assign the pointer to the one requested?

The memory is not allocated until `new` is actually called at runtime.

> Essentially, would this program run on computer where `MAX_INPUT_SIZE` exceeds the available RAM, but the actual `data_size` does not?

Yes.

> why does `new` force you to have an array size that resolves at compile time?

It doesn't.  Wherever did you get that idea?  Only *static arrays* need to have their size specified at compile-time.  *Dynamic arrays* do not.  One of the main benefits of using `new[]` is that you can supply it with a value that is not known until run-time.  For example:

```cpp
char *data;
long long int data_size;
/* receive input size */

data = new char[data_size];
```

Comment: Yes this is probably what I'm thinking of. What if I rephrased my question to ask about array declaration with dynamic sizing? Although it would make no sense, would my solution work to mimic dynamic sizing?

Comment: "*array declaration with dynamic sizing*" - that would be a so-called **variable length array** (VLA), which is **non-standard**, only supported as an extension in few compilers. The *standard* way to use dynamic length arrays is to use `new[]`, preferably `std::vector` instead. "*Although it would make no sense, would my solution work to mimic dynamic sizing?*" - I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mixed array declaration with `new` allocation.

With arrays:

```
#define this_has_to_be_compile_time_constant  50
// or: const int this_has_to_be_compile_time_constant = 50;
char array[this_has_to_be_compile_time_constant];
```

But with new:

```
int this_can_be_a_variable = some_function();
char *array = new char[this_can_be_a_variable];
```

Comment: Yes this is probably what I'm thinking of. What if I rephrased my question to ask about array declaration with dynamic sizing? Although it would make no sense, would my solution work to mimic dynamic sizing?

Comment: About what exactly? What is an "array declaration with dynamic sizing"?

Answer (score 0):

> - Cannot use vector or other wrappers (let's say we are looking for
>     extremely fast performance)

Just use a vector.

The following snippet is from running code.

- The size of gameboard object is not known at compile time.
- In my practice, gameboard is created empty, which takes no time at all.

  // create game-board - with a vector of cells

  CellVec_t  gameBoard;

So one line does the allocation effort after the size is determined. Options include default value, cmd line override, display max size, etc.

from  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector:

"Reallocations are usually costly operations in terms of performance. The 
 **reserve() function can be used to eliminate reallocations if the number of 
 elements is known beforehand.** "

Thus

```
gameBoard.reserve (static_cast<long unsigned int>(aMaxRow * aMaxCol));

GOLUtil_t  gBrd(aMaxRow, aMaxCol, gameBoard, *ansiTerm);

...
```

Size of gameboard.size() is 0 when reserve is called, and capacity is fully allocated after.