# How to take input to an array with unknown number of elements? ( I don't wanna use std::vector )

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

```
int n = 5;
int arr[n];
for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
    cout << "enter number" <<endl;
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

but what if the number of inputs is unknown? how can I take the unknown number of inputs in an array

Comment: You don't want to use dynamic arrays (e.g., `std::vector`), and you don't have valid C++ code in the snippet anyway, and you have an unknown number of elements.  You can have a very large array, say `int arr[1000000];` and use the portion that you need, and if the need exceeds the maximum available size you can throw an exception.

Comment: Sorry, but C++ does not work this way. In C++ the size of all arrays must be ***known at compile-time***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/static-array-vs-dynamic-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you do

```cpp
int arr[n];
```

the size of the array is decided, once and for all. There's no way you can change it.

On the other hand, you can dynamically allocate memory to which a pointer points to.

```cpp
int * arr;
arr = new int[n];
// now you can use this arr just like the other one
```

If you need, later, to change the size of the memory to which `arr` points, you can deallocate and reallocate as needed.

```cpp
delete [] arr;
arr = new int[m];
// probably there's a more idiomatic way of doing this, but this is really too
// much C for me to care about this details...
```

Obviously you need to think about how you can take care of copying the values to another temporary array to avoid loosing them during the deallocation-reallocation process.

All this madness, however, is not necessary. `std::vector` takes care of all of that for you. You don't want to use it? Fine, but you're not writing C++ then. Full stop.