# Variable length in a Simple Matrix c++

Tags: c++

I'm using VS 2019. In this code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Inserisci la dimensione della matrice:";
    int DIM;
    DIM = 2;
    cin >> DIM;
        int v[DIM][DIM];
    return 0;
}
```

I Don't understand why in:

```
int v[DIM][DIM];
```

I've this error:

*The expression must have a constant value. It is not possible to use the "DIM" variable value as a constant.*

Comment: This question was literally closed 2 minutes ago and the OP asked another with the exact same title and content, lol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static array vs. dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/static-array-vs-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: Yep. Just asking the same question again instead of addressing the raised concerns is just rude.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I bet OP be like: "Modern problems require modern solutions" .

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt First action in case of errors: retry

Comment: This approach is also known as "lazyweb".

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So you cannot write code like:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //incorrect
```

Correct way to write this would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //correct
```

So we cannot use the input given by the user as the size of the array. That is why you are getting the mentioned error.

You can use `std::vector` in place of built in array to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

some compiler/c++ version doesn't support variable length arrays compile time. we can create dynamic array on heap. Below code works for you

```
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    cout << "Inserisci la dimensione della matrice:";
    int DIM;
    DIM = 2;
    cin >> DIM;
    int **v = new int*[DIM];
    for (int i=0;i<DIM;i++)
        v[i] = new int[DIM];
    // now you can use it as 2D array i.e
    v[0][0] = 12;
    cout<<v[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, C++ doesn't suport VLAs at all. C does support them and some C++ compilers extend that support to C++ when compiled in non-strict mode.

Comment: Set your compilers to *strict* conforming to the ANSI/ISO standard and see if VLAs pass. :-)

Comment: If you are going to dynamically allocate memory, consider the case of allocating one contiguous block of memory (`DIM * DIM`) then casting or treating as a 2d array.