# How can I add a static assert to check if a variable is static?

Tags: c, static, static-assert

I have a macro which works well only on static local variables (since it uses inline assembly notation to extract data about the variable). I need a way to enforce that the input to the macro is indeed a static local variable:

correct:

```
func f()
{
    static int x;
    my_macro(x);
}
```

not correct:

```
func f()
{
    int x;
    my_macro(x);
}
```

I work with GCC for C (no C++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following trick:

```
#define ASSERT_LOCAL_STATIC(v) static void *p_ ## v = &v

void fn()
{
    int nonstatic_var = 0;
    static int static_var = 0;

    ASSERT_LOCAL_STATIC(static_var);
    ASSERT_LOCAL_STATIC(nonstatic_var);
}
```

GCC issues an error "initializer element is not constant" for non-static variables.

Comment: Thanks! This is really nice. However, I get: error : unused variable 'p_searchResp', when I do this trick. Do you know how to aboid this?

Comment: I figured this out: you can add memcpy(p_ ## v,&v,sizeof(v)) in the macro

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to tell static and local variables apart by using their addresses:

- Static variables are [stored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93039/507519) in either the .BSS or .DATA sections
- Local variables are stored in the stack

For example the output of the following program on my system

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f0() {
    int x = 0;
    printf("%p\n", &x);
}

void f1() {
    static int x = 0;
    printf("%p\n", &x);
}

int main() {
        f0();
        f1();

        return 0;
}
```

is this:

```
0x7fff1dc718dc
0x600900
```

*Where* each section and the stack are placed depends on the ABI of your platform, but you could use the address of a block-local variable to form a condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define check(var) { \
        int ___ = 0; \
        printf("%s (%p): %s\n", #var, &var, (&var > &___)?"local":"static"); \
}

void f0() {
    int x = 0;
    check(x);
}

void f1() {
    static int y = 0;
    check(y);
}

int main() {
        f0();
        f1();

        return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
x (0x7fff4b965afc): local
y (0x600978): static
```

Warning: I would not advise using this "trick". That's all it is: a trick, one that will break in the most unopportune of circumstances. Just document your macro properly and let the people who use it handle the aftermath of its misuse.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks! However, this is a run-time check and not a compile-time check.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do it in the way most C libraries use: Tell users that your macro works for static variables and the behavior for anything else may be undefined/unexpected.

Just like you can also pass NULL pointers to `strdup()` etc. which will result in nothing but a segfault there's not a big issue with not enforcing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot distinguish these cases in ISO C. But since you already mentioned that you use GCC there may be some helpful built-in pseudo functions. Their names all start with `__builtin_`, so you should read through that list in the GCC documentation.

http://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+builtin

Well, I just read through the whole built-ins section, and I didn't find anything. So I think it is really not possible.

What are you trying to do anyway with the macro, just out of curiosity?