# why do the removal of static give ' Stack overflow' error at the beginning of my program?

Tags: c, static, struct, stack-overflow

I use VC2010 and when i try to debug my progam with `struct` replacing `static` i get

> Unhandled exception at 0x000f18e7 in ht_array.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack
>   overflow.

it does it at the first line of main

```
#define BUCKETS 64
#define B_ENTRIES 50000

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
static fpinfo hash_table[BUCKETS][B_ENTRIES];
static tanker_record tr[100];
....
```

Comment: you just tried to put 3.2 MBytes at least on the stack, not a good idea, move the variable definitions outside of main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `64 * 50000 * sizeof(fpinfo)` bytes is apparently too big for your stack. With `static`, the variable is allocated in a different region of memory, where it does fit.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `static` means `hash_table` is now a stack variable whose size is too big for the stack.

`static` variables are stored elsewhere (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c)).