# where is a static variable inside a struct located?

Tags: c, static, struct

in C, if I declare a static variable inside a local strucutre, where does the static variable get placed ?
Since the struct is in the stack, will the static variable also be in the stack ?

Comment: Though the Q is tagged c, I feel the pressing need to ask *In what language c or c++?*, `static` structure member has no meaning in c unlike c++.

Comment: Yes. sorry I diddn't mention it though i tagged it under C.

Comment: If your intention was C and C++ both then retag it so and add a note saying so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I declare a static variable inside a local strucutre

In current C **the keyword `static` is meaningless inside a structure**. You should get an error from the compiler.

---

If by "static" you mean "not allocated using malloc": the member of a structure is always stored in the same place as the rest of the structure. If said member is a pointer, it can point to memory in the same region or not.

Comment: "static" haiku: Wonderful `static`; Keyword, object lifetime, scope;
Much more than `auto`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Awesomeness:-)) Is it your own ?

Answer (score 3):

In C++ static variables will be initialized when you first time use their class. In C they are not allowed since C compiler needs to store the whole struct in the same type of memory. About their storage see [Where are static variables stored (in C/C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c)