# C++ reference and lvalue

Tags: c++, function, reference

Can anybody please tell me what's happening in the following code. I was expecting lvalue error and it will happen if I remove the reference return type of the function. But it's giving me output as 20. Please explain. Thanks.

```
int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 20;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Don't forget the fact that `x` is static.

Comment: Probably made `x` static to get rid of a compiler warning about returning a reference to non-static local variable...

Comment: You don't get error because `x` is declared as having static linkage. As such even if the scope of `fun` exits `x` resides in a special implementation defined memory. check this SO question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c

Comment: @Sarath what exactly are you trying to accomplish, btw?

Comment: This is actually a variant of a very common idiom, used to access class member variables and items in containers. It's what makes `operator[]()` work the way you expect.

Comment: @40two Actually, `x` has *no linkage*, not static linkage (there's no such thing). What's static about `x` is its lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is as expected. In the call `fun() = 20;`, the *actual* `x` in `fun()` is assigned `20`, since `fun()` returns *reference* to `x`. In the call `cout<<fun();`, the assigned value is printed, which is `20`.

since `x` is declared `static`, it's available in memory even after `func()` returns.  A method scoped `static` variable is created when first encounter in the method, and retains until program terminates. `static` variable is initialized only *once*, and subsequent method call will see the last updated value. more on `static` [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html) and [here](http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/static-keyword.php).

Comment: Also worth noting that `x` is initialized only once.

Answer (score 2):

Basic C++ semantics:

- You can't assign to the return values of functions unless the return type is a reference.
- A function can't return a reference to a local variable unless it's a `static` variable.
- Static variables' values persist between accesses.

If you want to assign something to `x` outside of `fun()`, `x` has to live somewhere, right? Making it `static` gives it a permanent spot that will be re-accessed every time. That's why the value of `20` persists.