# static variables in C (declared in main). a mixup

Tags: c, arrays, static, stack

I am still a little fuzzy about static variables in C after reading some stuff:

according to [this](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf) PDF file (bottom of 1st page) , a static variable is saved in the "initialised data" segment of my executable.

On the other hand, I quote my book* on C language:

> On a system that allocates a relatively small run-time stack, one
>   might wish to declare large arrays as `static` variables in function
>   `main`. Then these arrays will not use up `stack` space.

Well from 1st link it does not look like as if a static variable (even an array) would ever use up stack space. So what is the deal?

*book is: "problem solving  & program design in C", by Jeri R. Hanly & Elliot B. Koffman, 3rd edition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c

Comment: Both links say the same thing - static variables are not allocated on the stack. The second link suggests that if you have a small stack, then you may want to declare large arrays as `static`, in order to avoid having them allocated on the stack. A more interesting question (in case you want to ask it) is - why would we ever declare arrays as non-static in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your sources state the same fact: static variables are not in the stack segment.

What your cited source states: static variables are not in the stack segment.

What your book says is: if you have a small stack, make variables static.

They are however still in the data segment of your program, not in the code segment. The **initial data segment** that your first source does cite, is, as the corresponding image shows, **outside of the stack and heap segment**.

Comment: ok and what is going to happen if I omit `static` from variables in main? Will I end up with a larger `stack` then? how would that be possible since it looks like the variable would never be stored in stack space?

Comment: @nass if you omit the `static`, they will be in the stack segment. What makes you believe, they wouldn't?