# Where located a const value?

Tags: c++, constants

In C++ (and other another programming language) dynamic variables located on the heap.
Static variables located on the stack.

Question: Where will a constant be located (const) (added to stack where function is called or in processor's registry or...)?

Comment: See [where are static variables stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c). Not on "the stack".

Comment: This depends entirely on the implementation. The standard makes no mention of either a 'stack' or a 'heap. Which implementation are you interested in knowing about?