# Assigning to string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am working with C and in the snippet below I think the assignment to `c` is OK. The assignments to `cArr[]` run OK but it doesn't seem right to me. It seems I should have to use something like:

```
char cArr[3][80];
```

Or are these strings being placed on the heap?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* c = "abcd";

    char* cArr[3];

    cArr[0] = "A string of of characters.";
    cArr[1] = "Another inane comment.";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**First case:**

```
char* c = "abcd";
```

`c` is of type `char *`. The base address of the string `"abcd"` is stored into that. Correct.

**Second Case:**

```
char* cArr[3];
```

`cArr` is an array of three `char *`s.

```
cArr[0] = "A string of of characters.";
cArr[1] = "Another inane comment.";
```

is also fine and legal. You're storing the base address of the string literals into a variable of type `char *` (here, `cArr[n]`). There is no issue with that.

> Or are these strings being placed on the heap?

Not really. Standards only specify that the string literals should have static storage duration. Usually string literals are placed in read-only memory locations so you may not be able to *modify* the strings pointed by `cArr[n]`. So, basically it's implementation dependent where the string literals are stored. As mentioned in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589985/2173917), strings are stored in the `.rodata` section of your binary.

Comment: @MattMcNabb sir, I have added a little description to my answer. Can you please review it?

Answer (score 1):

```
char* c = "abcd";
```

Makes a string literal and `c` points to the address of the first element.

```
char* cArr[3];
```

Creates an array of three `char*` pointers and the below statements can be used to make them point to string literals, which are `static`:

```
cArr[0] = "A string of of characters.";
cArr[1] = "Another inane comment.";
```

The above statements are perfectly valid. The string literals are allocated in the rodata memory segment and thus, they are read-only and are not writable.

Comment: They aren't on the heap. They're static.

Comment: Dosen't `static` imply that they are on the heap? Dosen't the same apply for global variables,i.e, they are allocated on the heap?

Comment: No. "heap" isn't an official term in C but common usage is the area in which  allocations made by `malloc` and family are stored. Historically it's called "heap" because the data structure named "heap" was used to track all those allocations. Also see [Where are static variables stored in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c)

Comment: I did a poor job on posing my question. 
Suppose cArr[] variable are dynamically determined as in:
    cArr[2] = strtok(NULL, delim);

vj

Comment: @Vince it doesn't matter as long as you don't need to copy whole string. Usually functions returning `char *` can have their result stored under pointer (as it is with your `cArr[i]`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb , Thanks for the link. I learnt a lot from it. I've edited my answer now. Does it look OK?