# What object keeps a strong reference to the app's UIApplicationDelegate?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm curious about the chain of object ownership in UIKit, going up from a UIViewController. Using the memory debugger in Xcode, I see that the `UIViewController` is owned (via a strong reference) by the `UIWindow`. The only strong reference to that `UIWindow` is from the app's `UIApplicationDelegate`.

The `UIApplicationDelegate` doesn't seem to have any inbound strong references (the `UIApplication` has a weak reference). What object actually *owns* the delegate and prevents it from being deallocated?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate): `the app delegate is a singleton object and is always present at runtime`.

Comment: Related: [Where are static variables stored (in C/C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93039/2415822)

Comment: @JAL: The application delegate is not a static variable. If you override `init` in AppDelegate and set a breakpoint then one can see that alloc/init is called on the application delegate in a _UIApplicationMainPreparations function. It *seems* that an associated reference is set to keep it alive. Unfortunately, the UIKit runtime is not open source, so it is difficult to tell how exactly it works.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, did not know that.  So does that mean the documentation is "technically" incorrect, since an internal UIApplication object is holding a reference to it somewhere and it's not a "true" singleton?

Comment: Most "singletons" are actually "shared instances". You (or I or Cal) define the AppDelegate class, and it is no problem to create another instance with `let ad  = AppDelegate()`. The documentation probably means: Some instance is created at startup and assigned to `UIApplication.delegate`.