# Huge static array vs a local array inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays, static

The piece of code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int function()
{
  const int N=10000000;
  std::array<double, N> array{0.0};
  std::cout<<"N="<<N<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int main(int, char **)
{
  function();
  exit(0);
}
```

When I launch the program, I see:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The program works only at`N<10000000`. I understand that the reason is the overflow of the stack. But if I were to declare the array static:

```
static std::array<double, N>{0.0};
```

everything works well up to `N=1000000000`. I was surprised.

As far as I can understand, the static `std::array` / `std::vector` inside a function is allocated in global memory (as if it was a static global array), not on the stack. That is why I can declare a static array inside a function that is much bigger than an ordinary array local to the function. Is it true?

Comment: In a word, yes :)

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-and-c? Also you forgot to name your array.

Comment: Oh, yes. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In word, yes.  :)

For completeness, it is worth mentioning that you can also allocate the array on the *heap*, by using the `new` operator.

You could also choose the store the data in a `std::vector`.  Performance/flexibility tradeoffs there are a little bit different to `std::array`, but the issue of stack size doesn't arise even for vectors that live on the stack (since the underlying storage is dynamically allocated).

Comment: I checked using local std::vector<double> vec(N, 0.0) without static instead of std::array. It works, but at N=10^9 my computer was frozen while with std::array it worked normally.

Comment: If to write std::array<double, N> array; without the initialization of the "array" with 0.0, the program works without segmentation fault even at N>10^7. Why?