# No memory is allocated while creating the class, then where variables in the class saved?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, computer-science

In object oriented programming, there is concept of class and objects. We define a class and then create its instance (object). Consider the below C++ example:

```
class Car{
  public:
   string model;
   bool petrol;
   int wheels = 4;
}

int main(){
   Car A;
   cout << A.wheels;

   return 0;
}
```

Now I know no memory was allocated to the class Car until the object A was created. Now I am swamped in the confusion that if no memory was allocated to the Car, then at the time of creating object A, how object A will know that wheels is equal to 4 ? I mean it should be saved somewhere in the memory.

Please ignore mistakes as it is a question from beginner's side :)

Comment: Memory *is* allocated. With automatic storage duration, which usually means "on the stack"

Comment: Memory is "allocated" for constants, whether they live in a class or outside a class.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-and-c

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of storage at work here.

The information about `Car` is stored in memory. That is the code in its methods, its layout, including the literal value `4` which initializes `wheels`. This exists in the binary executable file, and exists in memory at all times your application is running.

But when you say "no memory allocated.." you're thinking about memory of an *instance* of `Car`, where memory is allocated each time you create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ compiler generates executable code to default-initialize the class member to 4. The "saved somewhere in memory" you're referring to is compiler-generated executable code. Actual, executable code that constructs the object, and sets its class member to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Some programming languages have the notion of a "class object". That's an object that holds data about what's in a class: its members, its member functions, and its bases. C++ doesn't do that. The information about what's in a class is in the executable code that the compiler generates.

In the code in the question, when an object of type `Car` is created, the code that the compiler generates allocates a block of memory large enough for a `Car` object. The code "knows" where in that block the storage for `model` is, where the storage for `petrol` is, and where the storage for `wheels` is. Since the `wheels` member has an initializer, the code that the compiler generates also sets the value in the storage for `wheels` to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables in functions have automatic storage duration, which usually means they are allocated in the stack frame of the function.

If you compile your code and look at the generated assembly you will see the SP being adjusted to make space for the `Car` and `model` and `wheels` getting initialized. You will also see `std::string::~string()` being called at the end of `main` as part of what is left of the default destructor of `Car`.

I'm actually disappointed none of the compilers (gcc, clang, icc) figure out that you only access `A.wheels` and that `A.wheels` is 4 and that the `std::string` destructor has no side effect since they do figure out the constructor is a NOP and allocated nothing for an empty string.

I would hope the optimizer to optimize away the `Car` completely and only leave `std::cout << 4;`.

Comment: `-O3` does that https://godbolt.org/z/1Gqj3Mj8d

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, it doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/x4dr3e58G It still gets overwhelmed by the `std::cout <<` and drops that optimization. I feels like anything that can't be inlined breaks the optimizer.